# push won't work when called from other function

Tags: javascript

I don't know why push system doesn't work when a value is called from another function like this:

```js
var array=['alice','why'];
check(array);

function check(array) {
  var word = array[0].split("");
  again(word)
}

var already = [];

function again(word) {
  newWord = word.join("");
  console.log(word)
  console.log(newWord)
  console.log(typeof newWord)
  already.push(newWord);
}
```

if I insert a word inside the function it works. Like that:

```js
var already = [];
again();

function again() {
  word = ['a','l','i','c','e']
  newWord = word.join("");
  console.log(word)
  console.log(newWord)
  console.log(typeof newWord)
  already.push(newWord);
  console.log(already)
}
```

Where is the issue? I can't figure it out...
as you see on examples, word and  type of are equal on both examples

Comment: You called `check` before assigning to `already`, so `already` is `undefined` when you try to `push` to it...

Comment: ohh ye :D good point

Answer (score 1):

The `already.push(newWord);` is called before you initialize `var already = [];`.

It will work if you put it like this.

```js
var array = ['alice', 'why'];
var already = [];
check(array);

function check(array) {
  var word = array[0].split("");
  again(word)
}

function again(word) {
  newWord = word.join("");
  console.log(word)
  console.log(newWord)
  console.log(typeof newWord)
  already.push(newWord);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the already `array` at the top. It is giving `undefined` because the code reaches the array first and it is defined later.

```js
var already = [];
var array=['alice','why'];
check(array);

function check(array){
  var word = array[0].split("");
  again(word)
}
 
function again(word){
  var newWord = word.join("");
  console.log(word)
  console.log(newWord)
  console.log(typeof newWord)
  already.push(newWord);
  console.log(already)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions will be hoisted to the top and the same applies for the variables declarations (not the assignment). At the time the again function is called, the already variable is undefined. Declare and initialize your variables before use in the functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should define `already` before use it.

```
var array=['alice','why'];
var already = [];

check(array);

function check(array){
    var word = array[0].split("");
    again(word)
}

function again(word){
    newWord = word.join("");
    console.log(word)
    console.log(newWord)
    console.log(typeof newWord)
    already.push(newWord);
}
```